# Spring integration problem when reading file from ftp

Tags: spring, google-cloud-platform, spring-integration

I have a problem with spring integration, i try to read large zip file from ftp.
when spring integration download the file, some process not complete. 
i dont know why, that file still have .writing status and not continue the process

the next process if download proccess complete, file .writing should be deleted
but it not happen, because the process stoped.

but it not happened at my local env.

sorry for bad english.  hope you got my point.

```
@Configuration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@ConfigurationProperties("flight.datafeed.ftp.route.management")
@Getter
@Setter
@Slf4j
public class AutomaticRouteConfiguration {

  private int mode = 2;
  private String host;
  private int port;
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private String remoteDirectory;
  private long queueFixDelay;
  private long queueMaxMessagesPerPoll;
  private String directoryInput;
  private String directoryUncompress;
  private String failedDirectory;
  private String filterFileName;
  private String metadataStoreName;

  @Autowired
  private KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> kafkaTemplate;

  @Autowired
  private RouteManagementTransformer routeManagementTransformer;

  @Autowired
  private MongoDbMetadataStore metadataStore;

  @Value("${flight.datafeed.kafka.topic.routeManagement}")
  private String topic;

  @Bean
  public MongoDbMetadataStore metadataStore(MongoDbFactory factory) {
    return new MongoDbMetadataStore(factory, "integrationMetadataStore");
  }

  @Bean
  public DefaultFtpSessionFactory ftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    sf.setHost(host);
    sf.setPort(port);
    sf.setUsername(username);
    sf.setPassword(password);
    sf.setClientMode(mode);
    return sf;
  }

  @Bean
  public FtpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
    FtpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(
        ftpSessionFactory());
    fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
    fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("/");
    fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new FtpRegexPatternFileListFilter(filterFileName));
    return fileSynchronizer;
  }


  @Bean
  @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "automaticRouteFlow.input",
      poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "${flight.datafeed.ftp.route.management.ftpPoolerDelay}", maxMessagesPerPoll = "2"))
  public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
    log.info("pool to ftp");
    FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
        sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
    source.setMaxFetchSize(1);
    source.setLocalDirectory(new File(directoryInput));
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    source.setLocalFilter(fileFilters());
    return source;
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow automaticRouteFlow() {
    return p -> p
        .transform(unZipTransformer(), e -> e.advice())
        .split(new UnZipResultSplitter())
        .enrichHeaders(s -> s.headerExpressions(h -> h
            .put(FtpConstant.UNCOMPRESSED_DIR, "payload.getParentFile()")
            .put(FtpConstant.UNCOMPRESSED_FILE, "payload"))
            .header(FtpConstant.FAILED_PATH, failedDirectory)
        )
        .split(Files.splitter(true), e -> e.advice(fileHandlerAdvice()))
        .transform(o -> {
              try {
                return routeManagementTransformer.transform(o.toString());
              } catch (Exception e) {
                return new PollSkipAdvice();
              }
            }
        )
        .transform(Transformers.toJson())
        .filter(o -> !o.toString().equals("{}"))
        .channel(MessageChannels.publishSubscribe())
        .handle(kafkaMessageHandler(kafkaTemplate, topic),
            e -> {
              e.advice(directoryHandler());
            }
        );
  }

  @Bean
  public ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice fileHandlerAdvice() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice fileHandlerAdvice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    fileHandlerAdvice
        .setOnSuccessExpressionString("headers['" + FtpConstant.UNCOMPRESSED_FILE + "'].delete()");
    fileHandlerAdvice.setOnFailureExpressionString(
        "headers['" + FtpConstant.FILE_ORIGINAL + "'].renameTo(new java.io.File("
            + "headers['" + FtpConstant.FAILED_PATH + "']"
            + "+headers['" + FtpConstant.FILE_NAME + "']))");
    return fileHandlerAdvice;
  }

  @Bean
  public ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice directoryHandler() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice fileHandlerAdvice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    fileHandlerAdvice
        .setOnSuccessExpressionString("headers['" + FtpConstant.UNCOMPRESSED_DIR + "'].delete()");
    return fileHandlerAdvice;
  }


  private KafkaProducerMessageHandlerSpec<Integer, String, ?> kafkaMessageHandler(
      KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> kafkaTemplate, String topic) {

    return Kafka
        .outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate)
        .headerMapper(new SimpleKafkaHeaderMapper())
        .topic(topic).sync(false)
        .sendTimeout(queueFixDelay);
  }

  private FileListFilter fileFilters() {
    return new CompositeFileListFilter<>(Arrays.asList(
        new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore, "ftpFile:"),
        new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>()));
  }

  private UnZipTransformer unZipTransformer() {
    UnZipTransformer unZipTransformer = new UnZipTransformer();
    unZipTransformer.setZipResultType(ZipResultType.FILE);
    unZipTransformer.setWorkDirectory(new File(directoryUncompress));
    unZipTransformer.setDeleteFiles(true);

    return unZipTransformer;
  }

}
```

Comment: Some questions to help diagnose the issue:

 1. Does the *.writing* file keep growing with time, or does it stay at 0 bytes?
 2. Does the same thing happen with a *small* zip file?
 3. Which GCP environment are you running in?
 4. Try logging at INFO level. Are there any logs you can share?

Comment: 1. the .writing file is keep growing until the size 126Mb, and then process stop. not growing and nothing happen. total size is 131Mb

2. No problem with small size. <90 Mb, in some files also occur like point 1. 

3. Actually is happen at almost all server (Staging (AWS) and production (GCP) server), but not in my local.

4. there are nothing happen at the log.

Comment: @ElenaFelder i edited my post, you can see my configuration

Comment: Does the same issue happen if you customize the DefaultFtpSessionFactory bean like this: `sf.setClientMode(FTPClient.PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE);`. You can also try to set trace logging `log4j.category.org.springframework.integration.file=TRACE` as described in [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#default-factories)